# Is it possible to remove a soul from a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the portion of a soul inside a Horcrux without the person whose soul is actually in the Horcrux. I’m writing a Harry Potter fan fiction, and would really appreciate it if anyone could tell me.

Comment: Nominating to re-open, since this is not a duplicate. This question excludes the person who created the horcrux, perhaps as a way to defeat the soul fragment while preserving the object. The other question requires that the person who created the horcrux be the one to remove and re-integrate it into his/her soul. Additionally, duplicate questions [must both have accepted answers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance).

Comment: @Gaultheria - That policy only applies to Story-ID questions, not normal site questions.

Comment: @Gaultheria As Valorum said, the accepted-answer thing is a red herring for non-ID questions. However, you're right that these two questions are actually asking quite different things. Reopened.

Answer (score 3):

## It can be destroyed by damaging the Horcrux object past repair.

The piece of soul in Horcruxes can be destroyed, but the objects itself would have to be damaged beyond magical repair. It may remain somewhat intact, but it wouldn’t be “the same” as before the Horcrux is destroyed - it’d be at least some amount damaged, though possibly not totally ruined.

> “That’s a problem we’re going to have to solve, though, because ripping, smashing or crushing a Horcrux won’t do the trick. You’ve got to put it beyond magical repair.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 6 (The Ghoul in Pyjamas)*</sup></sub>

They were able to destroy the Dark Lord’s Horcruxes without his knowledge or consent, so this wouldn’t need the creator of the Horcrux to be present. The object needs to be damaged but doesn’t have to be completely annihilated - the Resurrection Stone in Marvolo Gaunt’s ring was cracked but the ring was still wearable and the stone remained in one piece despite the crack.

Comment: Moreover, the stone still worked!  Nobody even tried to repair it or anything, as far as I recall.